# adding leading zero if number is < 10

Tags: javascript

**Need extra '0' in front of day, hour, minute, second numbers when there are < 10.

Please help! Thanks!!**

```
            dateDiff: function(date1, date2){
                var diff = {}
                var tmp = date2 - date1;

                tmp = Math.floor(tmp/1000);
                diff.sec = tmp % 60;
                tmp = Math.floor((tmp-diff.sec)/60);
                diff.min = tmp % 60; 
                tmp = Math.floor((tmp-diff.min)/60);
                diff.hour = tmp % 24;
                tmp = Math.floor((tmp-diff.hour)/24);
                diff.day = tmp;

                return diff;
            },
```

Comment: In JavaScript you need to differentiate between Numbers(0)and Strings("0"). You are always returning a number. If you return a string you can prefix it with a ("0" + 1) when the number is smaller 10.

Comment: how can I convert Numbers to Strings in this case? thanks for your help!

Comment: if you add a string to a number it will become a string. Example: var result = "0" + 1; result will be "01";  Or you can use toString: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [slice method](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
diff.sec = tmp % 60;
if( diff.sec < 10 ){
    diff.sec = ("0" + diff.sec).slice(-2);
}
```

JSFiddle with sample value

```js
var test = 9;
if( test < 10 ){
  test = ("0" + test).slice(-2);
}
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this function

```
function addZero(number)
{
 if(number<10)
    return "0"+number;
 else
    return number;
}
```